# how run function onload for all spans of class "alt"?

Tags: jquery, indexing, onclick, onload, html

Here is the function I have now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.alt').click(function() {
       var index=   $(this).attr("data-text-index");
     var text = $.parseJSON($(this).attr("data-text"));
     if(index== null)
         index = -1;
     index = Number(index)+1>=text.length? 0:Number(index)+1;
     $(this).html(text[index]);
     $(this).attr("data-text-index",index);
  });
});
</script>

I <i class="alt" data-text='["like","love"]'></i> <i class="alt" data-text='["her","you"]'></i>.
```

**Question:**

how do I also run this function upon page load for each  tag of class "alt," populating it with its first data-text option, thus yielding the text "I like her", while retaining the ability to change the individual words "like" or "her" upon click?

Comment: Do whatever you want in callback of .each() call `$('.alt').each(function() { console.log(this); }).click(/* your previous code */)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, Use the below code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.alt').click(function() {
       var index=   $(this).attr("data-text-index");
     var text = $.parseJSON($(this).attr("data-text"));
     if(index== null)
         index = -1;
     index = Number(index)+1>=text.length? 0:Number(index)+1;
     $(this).html(text[index]);
     $(this).attr("data-text-index",index);
  });
  $('.alt').click(); //add this line in your code it will execute on page load and perform the click event
});
</script>
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! You've just made my life so much easier. If I may ask: Do you know if there's a way to store users' personalization "selections" in a user profile, such that when the user returns to a page, even if cache has been cleared, he/she will see the text personalized as before? Also, how do I link two <i> tags (for example, by giving them the same ID) such that if the user clicks one of them, both cycle to the next option within their respective data-text indexes?

Comment: @BradHubisz I think, your question is too big and you need to explain it. So can you post your question on my blog http://zenddevelopers.wordpress.com/ here I will give you full support.

Comment: OK, just posted to your blog, thanks! Note: the examples text didn't show up in my comment, but I think you'll get the idea anyway.